# php session_destroy browser remembering username and password

Tags: php

I am using the php authentication method for digest authentication as shown on the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php). All is working well except for the logout part.

I am using `session_destroy()` to try and log my users out, which it does. However my problem is if the user goes to log back in before closing the browser out they are not prompted for a username and password and they are automatically logged back in with the last username and password they entered.

It seems the credentials are somehow being remembered by the browser. In Firefox if I manually clear "active logins" in the "clear browsing history" before trying to log back in then I am prompted for the username and password even though the user has been logged out with `session_destroy()`.

I am also using [an example from the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to clear the cookie but that doesn't seem to help, it doesn't seem to be a cookie problem.

Here is my logout.php code

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
//destroy cookie if it exists
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
//destroy session
session_destroy();
header("location:form.php");
exit();
?>
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try to call unset($_SESSION['']) before you destroy the session.

Comment: @Jay
That didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP Auth works slightly different then authentication with session.
The only possibility to clear a http Auth session is to change the realm name.
Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#100396 (Comment #100396) it's where I found out.

BTW: It's a lot easier to use sessions for authentication, you have a lot more possibilities to store user information etc. so if there is no certain reason for httpAuth you might be better with using sessions.

Comment: Thanks for that link I will study up. I am new to this and was not aware there was an alternative. Can you point me to some good documentation on how to do what you are referring to as "sessions for authentication"? Thanks!!!

Comment: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/basic-user-authentication.aspx is a very simple tutorial on how to do a session auth. This one only handles auth for one hardcoded user but it would be easy to combine it with mysql or so. This one describes a easy multiuser authentication. http://phpsense.com/php/php-login-script.html

Comment: I backup Jonas - using sessions is hell lot easier than doing http auth. You can read how things are stored in sessions from the php manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php. :)

Comment: Oh god, I have to disagree completely that doing anything other than using a robust, totally pre-configured php auth system is better or easier than http auth.  The potential to screw up php session based auth is endless endless endless.  You have to hash passwords, preferrably with bcrypt, prevent distributed cracking attempts, try not to transfer passwords in the clear, it's an endless nightmare.  Use http auth unless you -must- use a lot of users with login & logout capability.

Answer (score 0):

session destroy won't delete the items stored in the session.
You can unset them manually :

```
function destroySession(){
    foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v)
        unset($_SESSION[$k]); 
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: That is very inefficient. Just do

    `$_SESSION = array();`

Comment: @spaghettiwestern sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You say when they push back, they are logged in again. Are you sure they are not actually logging in again when they push back by resending the login form? In your login function, at the very end, try doing a:

```
header("location: ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Or adjust to whatever URI they need to go to when they log in. This will prevent the user from resubmitting the form by pushing the back button.

Comment: No sir. See the answer from Jonas above. I tested this myself. When I log out I really get logged out. The problem is if I fail to close my browser before logging back in I am not prompted for a username and password. The browser is storing this information. If I send a 401 Unauthorized error to the client with the same "Realm" name then this browser information is cleared. The problem is I will get prompted for a username and password by doing this. Its hard to explain clearly.

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked the fact that you were using http-auth.